# Read all the messages in inbox

Tags: android, react-native

I am new to react-native.I am trying to build a simple android application that reads all the messages from the inbox and display it in a listview. In android,i can read all the messages using URI.
How can i read all the messages in a similar way using react-native?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

In React native,you want to read sms from android phone:

**react-native-get-sms-android**

This module that supports interaction with the Messaging API on Android

The package allows you to:
•   get messages
•   send messages
•   delete messages
Refer this for this module integration:[react-native-get-sms-android](https://github.com/briankabiro/react-native-get-sms-android#readme)

Make sure that you need specific permissions to read SMS for android.
For checking permissions in android,use **PermissionsAndroid** API.It provides access to Android M's new permissions model.For more details check this [docs](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/permissionsandroid)

**react-native-android-sms-listener**

To listen for the new messages in your app use this library.This library allows you to listen for incoming SMS messages.
Refer this for this module integration:[react-native-android-sms-listener](https://github.com/andreyvital/react-native-android-sms-listener)

Comment: If you find helpful answer,please accept any answer and close the question.

Answer (score 0):

Remember that everything that you did in Android, you can still do it in react Native, writing a Native Module, and here is a well explained example of how to do that https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/native-modules-android

Or I saw that there is this external library https://github.com/briankabiro/react-native-get-sms-android, that you might try.